# After button click label goes up in left upper corner

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have set auto-layout for the label so it should be centered right above my button, however when I click on the button the label goes up in the left corner. I'm a totally new beginner to coding, so bare in mind I might have just missed something very simple? I would guess in my code I need some kind of way to tell the position of the label to be after the click?

This is my code for the button action:

```
        nextStagetwo.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        nextStagetwo.userInteractionEnabled = true
        nextStagetwo.text = "Go to next stage"
        self.view.addSubview(nextStagetwo)

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        nextStagetwo.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    }


}


func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("stagethree")
    self.presentViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your application in Xcode 7 and select the debugger view and then the debugger toolbar button with tooltip, "Debug View Hierarchy" (third button from right in the debugger toolbar). That will show you what auto layout is computing for each item on the screen. You can peel off layers as needed in this view. Compare those values with your auto layout constraints for that item and its containers.

Also, make sure you don't have any auto layout warnings in the Xcode Interface Builder for your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the respons! I have done what you said and I can also see how it is in the left corner and I can see it doesnt have any constraint in this debugger view, however in normal view it shows as it has constraints? and I tried to remove them and add new ones, but it is still in the left corner? is there something I can change from this debugger view?

Comment: You said that in debugger view it doesn't have any constraint and yet it has constraints in normal view. I'm not sure what is going on. In the debugger view, if you select the "Size Inspector" it should show all the constraints on any selected view and then it grays out the ones that are not affecting the layout. So, you should see the very same constraints as you do in the normal storyboard editor.

Comment: It shows there is not constraint for it, but my theory is it is because I have put constraints on it when it is not" active". By saying "active" I mean it I have set its layout for before you click my button, but after the click of my button there is no constraints. I think this is the issue. However I dont know how I can set constraint for the label after the click? I guess this has to be manually coded in the swift file and not in the xcode interface?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the code, which was what was missing in my code:

```
let nextStagetwo = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(250, 250, 250, 250))
nextStagetwo.center = CGPointMake(210, 200)
```